# Blocking a url with a chrome extension, then showing a custom page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple website blocker in chrome, but after blocking a URL (for example `https://example.com`), I'd like to render my own custom HTML file that tells the user that the page has been blocked. **It's important to me that when the custom blocked page is shown, the URL is still `example.com`**.

I figured out how to block the URL using the webRequest API, but the only way I can see to show a custom page saying that the website has been blocked is to redirect the user, which obviously won't work for my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting/blocking try stopping the page and show your UI as standard DOM.

background script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(info => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(info.tabId, {
    file: 'stop.js',
    runAt: 'document_start',
  });
}, {
  urls: ['*://foo/*'],
  types: ['main_frame'],
});
```

stop.js - running as a content script

```
window.stop();
// reset DOM
document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html>');
// create your UI
document.body.textContent = 'blocked';
```

You can load your UI in an iframe pointing to an html file declared in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to fix it by specifying my custom html page in `"web_accessible_resources"` in the manifest.

For further reading, [check here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/)